# Adding new product causes foreign key constraint error

Tags: magento-2.0

I am unable to add new products to my Magento2 install that I have inherited.

I'm getting the following error:

> `` SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`tapetstore_magento2`.`catalog_product_entity_varchar`, CONSTRAINT
>   `CAT_PRD_ENTT_VCHR_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity_original` (`ent),
>   query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_varchar`
>   (`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?),
>   (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?),
>   (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?),
>   (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?)
>   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = VALUES(`value`) ``

I'm not sure how to correct this, any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

- For avoiding forign key set SET foreign_key_checks = 0; before uploading database and then later after importing change it back to SET foreign_key_checks = 1;

  Please refer this link

  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965424/1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails